# <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST"/>

Tags: c#, angular, security, asp.net-web-api

I have an API with one GET method that return few records related to students in a college which is coming from angular as jsonresult. Now I want to change method from GET to POST and also I want to add in Angular's web.config file(in UI) this config : . But its throwing 500 internal server error. Can someone please help me on this? Thanks in advance.
Headers added:

My Angular code for API is:

```
 getName() 
  {
    const studentdata = {RollNo: localStorage.getItem('RollNo')};
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:/api/Data/GetName', studentdata)
    .pipe(map((response: any) => response.json()))      
    .toPromise();
  }
```

My webAPI C# Code:

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    [System.Web.Http.Route("GetName")]
    public JsonResult GetName([FromBody]StudentServices.Models.DisplayNameModel studentdata)
    {
         //some SQL code
    }
```

Comment: I think about model binding is trying to bind a property without same types.

Comment: Headers added:

<customHeaders>  
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src img-src 'self' *.college.com child-src 'self' https: wss: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' ;frame-ancestors *.college.com" />  
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST" /> </customHeaders>

Comment: @BrewertonSantos Do you have any suggestion what should be done instead?

Comment: u enabled cors?